# Configure GitLab CI to deploy to heroku

Tags: heroku, continuous-integration, gitlab

I'm trying to set up my GitLab CI to deploy demo code to Heroku, I followed some reading online and I am having some issues

This is the error I get (From the GitLab CI):

```
$ git remote add heroku https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/MyApp.git
$ git push -f heroku master
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://heroku:MyAPI@git.heroku.com/MyApp.git'
```

This is a part of my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
deployment:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - git remote add heroku https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/MyApp.git
  - git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to commit before pushing.

Answer (score 0):

The following commands are going to solve your issue:

```
touch README
git add README

git add .
git commit -m 'reinitialized files'
git push origin master --force
```